# How to remove table row space?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a HTML email signature for outlook.

Here is my full code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <!-- 25408f
            3f4b54 -->
</head>

<body>
  <table border="0" style="width: 329px; height: 317px; font-size: 14px; border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="man.jpg">
      </td>
      <td align="right">
        <p style="font-family: Helvetica">
          <span style="color: #3f4b54;">
         Sean Clough <br/>
      Writer/Owner <br/>
       </span>
          <span style="color : #25408f; font-weight: bold;">
      Clough Copywriting
       </span>
        </p>

        <p style="font-family: Helvetica">
          <span style="color : #25408f; font-weight: bold;">m</span> 0419 031 052 <br/>
          <span style="color : #25408f; font-weight: bold;">a</span> PO Box 439 <br/> Bedford WA 6052
        </p>
        <p style="font-family: Helvetica; font-weight: bold; color : #25408f; text-decoration: underline;">
          cloughcopywriting.com.au
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: #001ae5; padding: 0; margin : 0;">
      <td>
        <p>Follow me on</p>
        <p>
          <img src="fb.jpg">
          <img src="gplus.jpg">
          <img src="instagram.jpg">
        </p>
      </td>
      <td align="right">
        <img src="logo-4.jpg">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" style="padding: 0; margin : 0; line-height: 0;">
        <img src="bottom.jpg">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Using above code the html view is like that image:[image]

Now I have problem about row space. In the last row you can see a gap. How can I remove it? I have used `line-height` but no luck with that.

Can you tell me how can I remove this space?

Thanks.

Comment: Please make a working fiddle.

Comment: your font-size:14 seems to be the culprit

Comment: @mplungjan let me check it.

Answer (score 2):

try to use `vertical-align: baseline;` on tr

Comment: glad to hear that

Comment: I am using same `vertical-align: baseline` for the man image. but can't remove the space. How can I do this?

Comment: Fixed it, Thanks.